# retrieve atom:id from XML

Tags: php, xml

How do you retrieve the value in `atom:id` from a XML document?

```
<atom:entry xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
    <atom:id>http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/profiles/domain/mydomain.com/full/test</atom:id>
</atom:entry>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use SimpleXML and XPath for that:

```
$xml = <<<XML
<atom:entry xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
     <atom:id>http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/profiles/domain/mydomain.com/full/test</atom:id>
</atom:entry>
XML;

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);

$result = $xml->xpath('/atom:entry/atom:id');

foreach ($result as $curResult)
{
    echo __FILE__ . ':' . __LINE__ . '<pre>' . print_r($curResult, 1) . '</pre>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [simple_xml](http://php.net/simple_xml) and an [xpath](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) query. Like so:

```
$xml = <<<EOF
<atom:entry xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
    <atom:id>http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/profiles/domain/mydomain.com/full/test</atom:id>
</atom:entry>
EOF;

$doc = simplexml_load_string($xml);

$el = $doc->xpath('//atom:id');

echo (string)$el[0];
```

(obviously that's without error checking and all)